# How to run regression when formula is given by a string?

Tags: r, string, regression, formula

Let's consider data following:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame("Exp" = rexp(100), "Norm" = rnorm(100), "Wei" = rweibull(100, 1))
```

I want to perform linear regression but when formula is a string in format:

```
form <- "Exp + Norm + Wei"
```

I thought that I only have to use:

```
as.formula(lm(y~form, data = df))
```

However it's not working. The error is about variety in length of variables. (it seems like it still treats form as a string vector of length 1, but I have no idea why).

Do you know how I can do it ?

Comment: Exactly the one you put in your answer! Thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` to construct the formula, and use it directly on `lm`

```
lm(paste('y ~', form), data = df)
```

-output

```
#Call:
#lm(formula = paste("y ~", form), data = df)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          Exp         Norm          Wei  
#   0.495861     0.026988     0.046689     0.003612
```